# Shiny: passing input$var to aes() in ggplot2

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to write a Shiny app graphing the density of a variable VAL, by categories of age (AGE) or sex (SEX). The user selects "SEX" or "AGE" in the dropdown menu, and I have been trying to use `fill = input$Group_select` in ggplot and ggvis.

In ggplot:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(gdat[gdat$GFR==input$GFR_select,]) + 
                      aes(x= VAL, fill=input$Group_select) +
                      geom_density(adjust=input$slider1))
```

**EDIT: as docendo pointed out, this can be fixed for ggplot using aes_string:**

```
output$plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(gdat[gdat$GFR==input$GFR_select,]) + 
                              aes(x= VAL) +
                              geom_density(adjust=input$slider1, aes_string(fill=input$Group_select))):
```

In ggvis:

```
gvis <- reactive(subset(gdat, GFR==input$GFR_select) %>% 
                 ggvis(x = ~VAL) %>% group_by_(input$Group_select) %>%
                 layer_densities(adjust = input$slider1) %>%
                 add_axis("y", title = "Density", ticks="none") %>%
                 scale_numeric("x", domain = c(0, 230)) ) 
gvis %>% bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")
```

**SOLUTION: using as.name(input$Group_select) will render the graph properly!**

This is (was) what is rendered: [Imgur link to shiny output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsds2.jpg). Interestingly, it seems that group_by_ correctly interprets input$Group_select, whereas input$Group_select is treated as a constant in `fill=input$Group_select`

Any ideas on how I could get the plots to render correctly?

Here is the full Shiny code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("eGFR in the ARIC study"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Group_select",
                label=h3("By-Variable"),
                choices=c("AGE","SEX","ALL"),
                selected="SEX"),
    selectInput("GFR_select",
                label=h3("Creatinine Measure"),
                choices=c("BOTH", "CREATININE", "CYSTATIN", "MDRD"),
                selected="MDRD"),
    sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Bandwith Adjustment"),
                min = 0.5, max = 4, value = 1)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("ggvis_ui"),
    ggvisOutput("ggvis"),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
source("helpers.R")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  gvis <- reactive(subset(gdat, GFR==input$GFR_select) %>% 
                     ggvis(x = ~VAL, fill = ~input$Group_select) %>% group_by_(input$Group_select) %>%
                     layer_densities(adjust = input$slider1) %>%
                     add_axis("y", title = "Density", ticks="none") %>%
                     scale_numeric("x", domain = c(0, 230)) ) 
  gvis %>% bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")
  output$plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(gdat[gdat$GFR==input$GFR_select,]) + 
                          aes(x= VAL, fill=input$Group_select) +


      geom_density(adjust=input$slider1))
})
```

Comment: Perhaps you need  to use `aes_string`

Comment: Thank you, solves it for ggplot! any thought about the ggvis one?

Comment: Not really, did you try `fill = eval(input$Group_select)`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it simply changes the legend header to, literally, "eval(input$Group_select)" instead of "input$Group_select"

Comment: as.name(input$Group_select) seems to work for ggvis! Note that aes(as.name(input$Group_select)) will not work for ggplot; aes_string seems required there

Comment: Post your solution below as an answer below, [self-answer is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: `eval(as.name(input$Group_select))` worked for me

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure this is still an open question, but an alternative to the `aes_string` would be to convert the string to a symbol:

```
library(ggplot2)

# usually you can put all the shared aesthetics in the first line
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, colour = cyl)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```
# when the input is a string, you can use aes_string(), but you'd
# have to enter the string var separately, or change all vars..

input <- "cyl"

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point(aes_string(colour = input))

# or
# ggplot(mtcars, aes_string("mpg", "hp", colour = input)) +
#  geom_point()
```

[image]

```
# you can put the converted string var in the normal aes()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, colour = !!as.symbol(input))) +
  geom_point()

# note: as.name() and as.symbol() are aliases
```

[image]

Created on 2018-11-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).