# How to use the rlang `!!!` operator to define a function that wraps around a ggplot call? (Error: Can't use `!!!` at top level)

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

## Context

Reading the vignette [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming) I tried to use the `...` and `!!!` operators to implement a function that would wrap around ggplot functions and would accept an arbitrary number of arguments that would define which variables in a dataframe were to be mapped to each aesthetic.

## My goal

I wanted to define a function `plot_points2()` such that

1. `plot_points2(df, x = x, y = y, color = z)` would be equivalent to `df %>% ggplot( mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = z) ) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1)`
2. `plot_points2(df, x = x, y = z, color = y)` would be equivalent to `df %>% ggplot( mapping = aes(x = x, y = z, color = y) ) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1)`
3. `plot_points2(df, x = x, y = z)` would be equivalent to `df %>% ggplot( mapping = aes(x = x, y = z) ) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1)`

## What failed

### packages

```
require(tidyverse)
require(rlang)
```

### reduced example dataset

```
df <- tibble(g1= sample(x = c(1,2,3), replace = T, size = 10000),
             g2= sample(x = c("a","b","c"), replace = T, size = 10000),
             x = rnorm(10000, 50, 10),
             y = rnorm(10000, 0, 20) + x*2,
             z = rnorm(10000, 10, 5))
df
```

### my attempt

```
plot_points2 <- function(d, ...){
  args <- quos(...)
  print(args)
  ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(!!!args)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
}
plot_points2(df, x = x, y = y, color = z)
```

### the error

```
Error: Can't use `!!!` at top level
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

## Why I think it should work

I figure what I wanted to acomplish isn't much different from an example in the [vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming) that uses these operators to make a function that wraps around `mutate()`, and passes multiple arguments that defined the grouping variables (in deed I was able to implement a function that does that to the example dataset above I'm posting as an example), but somehow the latter works and the former doesn't:

### this works

```
add_dif_to_group_mean <- function(df, ...) {
  groups <- quos(...)
  df %>% group_by(!!!groups) %>% mutate(x_dif = x-mean(x), 
                                        y_dif = y-mean(y), 
                                        z_dif = z-mean(z))
}

df %>% add_dif_to_group_mean(g1)
df %>% add_dif_to_group_mean(g1, g2)
```

### this doesn't

```
plot_points2 <- function(d, ...){
  args <- quos(...)
  print(args)
  ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(!!!args)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
}
plot_points2(df, x = x, y = y, color = z)
```

I also read that the problem could be related with `aes()` being evaluated only when the plot is printed, but in that case I think using `!!` and **unpacking manually should raise the same error but it doesn't**:

```
plot_points2b <- function(d, ...){
  args <- quos(...)
  print(args)
  ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = !!args[[1]], 
                                 y = !!args[[2]],
                                 color = !!args[[3]])) + 
    geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
}
plot_points2b(df, x = x, y = y, color = z)
```

In deed this last example works fine if you plot 3 variables, but it doesn't allow you to plot a number of variables different from 3

eg: `plot_points2b(df, x = x, y = z)` is not equivalent to

```
df %>% ggplot( mapping = aes(x = x, y = z) ) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
```

In stead it raises the error:

```
Error in args[[3]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Anyone knows what concept am I missing here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried your first ggplot block that you say is working, which was surprising to me since you are calling the function with objects `x` and `y` that don't exist (which is also the message I got.  Are you sure you don't mean `"x"` and `"y"`?   Double check your environment to make sure that x and y don't exist there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345782/shiny-passing-inputvar-to-aes-in-ggplot2   This also explains other ways to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific use case is an example in `?aes`. `aes` automatically quotes its arguments. One can simply directly pass the dots. Try:

```
plot_points3 <- function(d, ...){
  print(aes(...))
  ggplot(d, aes(...)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
}
plot_points3(df, x = x, y = y, color = z)
```

This nicely prints:

> ```
> Aesthetic mapping: 
> * `x`      -> `x`
> * `y`      -> `y`
> * `colour` -> `z`
> ```

And yields the required plot.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, I think you may already have x and y in your environment and that is why some of your code is working.  I'm not totally sure what you are trying to achieve but I think you are doing too much rlang for getting your code to run without error.

For example:

```
plot_points <- function(d, ...){    
    ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
     geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
}
plot_points (df, x, y)
```

will make your plot without any reason to add the overhead and complexity of `!!!` or `enquo()`.

You were on this path here too, where this much simpler code works fine:

```
add_dif_to_group_mean <- function(., ...) {

    df %>% group_by(g1) %>% mutate(x_dif = x-mean(x), 
                                          y_dif = y-mean(y), 
                                          z_dif = z-mean(z))
}

df %>% add_dif_to_group_mean(g1)
```

Likewise:

```
plot_points2 <- function(d, ...){
    ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, color=z)) + 
    geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
}
plot_points2(df, x = x, y = y, color = z)
```

works fine from what I can tell.

So I understand that maybe you are working through the examples in the book, which is great.  But I think there is a missing issue somewhere that would make it so you have to do all the extra stuff in a real world function. For example, maybe you want to pass in strings like `"x"` and `"y"` instead of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Hello Elin, first of all thank you for your answer.  
I don't understand why you cannot run the code since I can run it with a fresh environment (which I get by pressing ctrl+shift+f10 on R Studio - it should do the trick, right? otherwise let me know how you are supposed to do it).

Comment: __What I am trying to achieve__ is to define a function that will take the names of the columns as arguments and uses them to call `ggplot`. __In your first example__ (`plot_points`), the plot is the one intended only because you are plotting the columns x and y (if you passed any other arguments to your `plot_points()` the plot would remain the same). For instance, if you were to plot the columns x against z ggplot would still plot x against y. Try calling `plot_points(df, x, z)` to see for yourself.

Comment: As for __your second and third examples__, they too ignore the arguments you pass them (except for the dataframe) i.e: if you call `df %>% add_dif_to_group_mean(g1, g2)` it will still group using only the column g1, and if you call `plot_points2(df, x = z, y = x, color = y)` it will still map x to the horizontal axis, y t the vertical axis and z to color.

Comment: As for __the complexity of `!!!` and `enquo`:__ from what I could understand in what I read, when you pass an argument to a function in R it doesn't have to be defined yet since it is only evaluated when it is needed. The `enquo` and `!!` (or `!!!` in case of multiple arguments catched with `...`) should allow you to then pass the argument as an expression to another function inside the one you are defining (in this case the inner function would be `ggplot()`) still without being evaluated. It was to validate this idea that I included the example `add_dif_to_group_mean`, which I believe works.

Comment: Finally, I would ask you to please post a working example of what you meant by __passing _in strings like "x" and "y" instead of x and y___. I did try to use an aproach along those lines to the problems I describe above before reading about tidyeval, but I couldn't get it to work and after reading [this vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.htm) I was under the impression tidyeval was the way to do it.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than writing clarifications in comments.  Also try to just ask one question per question.

Comment: Hello again, I’m afraid I can’t see how I could make my question more clear. Do you have any sugestions? Please feel free to edit it yourself if you think you can make it so.  My intention with each of the comments above was to point out why I believe each part of your answer didn’t apply to the question, so I thought comments to your answer would be the best place to do so.

Comment: You wrote a bunch of comments attempting to make it more clear.  Try rewriting and breaking up the giant code blocks with detailed explanations of what you don't understand, what you think should be happening and what did happen instead for each block.  Get rid of anything that is a distraction from the one question you want to ask.  I think the answer is probably that you are expecting ggplot to work like dplyr but it does not, it is older and different. But there could be a different question there, not sure at this point.