# Refer to column name that is dependent on input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have seen in other questions about how to name a column based on an input in Shiny. I'm trying to refer to the column name to continue performing further actions with the column.

The below example is simplistic, but essentially I am trying to achieve something with a column without knowing what the column name will be. In the real data, there are a lot more possible options.

The below creates a new column rather than reworking the column I am trying to refer to. I have also tried the somewhat obviously nonsensical `score_data$(input$selection)`, but unsurprisingly that doesn't run.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  selectInput(
  "selection", label = "Select",
  choices = c("Harriet", "Louise")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
      htmlOutput("table"))
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  output$table <- renderTable({
    person_a <- c(95, 60)
    Terry <- c(77, 81)
    score_data <- data.frame(person_a, Terry)
    colnames(score_data)[1] <- input$selection
    name <- input$selection
    score_data$name <- c(90, 60)
    return(score_data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think that you are using `()`  where you should be using `[]`  .  For example try `score_data[input$selection]`.  What are you trying to do here? `score_data <- data.frame(person_a, Terry)`

Comment: @Elin `score_data <- data.frame(person_a, Terry)` is creating a data frame, the `()` used for this is correct. I think once the data.frame `score_data` is created, the OP is trying to change a column name using a user input.

Comment: In the real application how will this work? Here is a problem I see, you are changing the name of the first column, and doing so using index `[1]`, if this is how it is to work in the actual app (column 1 always being desired), why not simply subset the data based on the index? If this is not the case and you plan to subset data that exists at an ever changing index, how are you going to know where the column exists since there are no column names to begin with? I think I just need to understand why you want to do this in order to give you a good answer.

Comment: Your code right now would (if "Harriet" is selected) return a data frame with 3 columns  "Harriet", "Terry" and "name".   Because you replaced the original person_a name with "Harriet" and then added a new variable called name.    This `name <- input$selection` doesn't really do anything since `name` is not returned.  The name column you added has values 90 and 60, while the Harriet column has 95 and 60.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to possibly creates `score_data["Harriet"]  but you are doing it two ways, and as you noticed one of them is not working.   Either do it the first way (with the col_names() function)  or do `score_data[,input$selection] <- c(90,60)`.   But one thing that is confusing is that you are (I think) trying to set the Harriet column to two different values in the same function.

Comment: It's not a 100% duplication but look at how a similar issue is solved in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345782/shiny-passing-inputvar-to-aes-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I think the best thing to do is @Chabo 's suggestion of simply indexing - if I do that and then rename the column to something actually known, the rest of it is fine. Apologies for the basic example I gave - I appreciate that in the example it is a weird thing to do, but my actual code would have overcomplicated things. For clarity, I wasn't trying to assign different values to the column - I was trying to change it (not because that is what I need to do in reality, but just to demonstrate an example of needing to refer to a column where the name would be unknown).