# R shinyApp app works, but has too many "if" and "else" statemtents in my . Need to simplify

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, simplify

Full code available here: https://github.com/donwillmar/dataviz/blob/master/Evomass_RUG(app.R)

I have made a functioning `shinyApp` that compares positions in a rugby team across 3 metrics from one dataset.

In the  data-set, the observations are laid out like this:

```
| Year | Name | Nation |   Zone    | KG | CM  | BMI |
| 2019 |  Bob |  USA   |  Flyhalf  | 80 | 183 | 23  |
```

There are 7 different positions in `~Zone` and I have compared each across the metrics `KG`, `CM` and `BMI` in separate `ggplots`. There are 111 plots in total and I have saved them as a list called `plots.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("superhero"),
titlePanel("Mass Evolution of Rugby Internationals"),
sidebarPanel(position = "left",
             wellPanel(h3("Variables"),
                       radioButtons(inputId = "yvar", label = h4("Mass Metric"), 
                                    choices = list("Body Mass Index" = "BMI", "Weight (KG)" = "KG","Height (CM)" = "CM"),
                                    selected = "BMI"),

                       selectInput(inputId = "zone", label = h4("Position Zone"), 
                                   choices = list("Front Row", "Second Row", "Back Row",
                                                  "Scrumhalf", "Flyhalf", "Centre", "Outside Back"),
                                   selected = "Front Row"),

                       selectInput(inputId = "comp", label = h4("Compare Position"), 
                                   choices = list("None", "Front Row", "Second Row", "Back Row",
                                                  "Scrumhalf", "Flyhalf", "Centre", "Outside Back"),
                                   selected = "None")
```

In the `server.R` function, I have put 111 `if` and `else` statements call the corresponding `ggplot` from the `plots` list, based on user's `input$zone` and `input$compare`

```
server <- function(input, output) {

selectedData <- reactive({
    c(input$yvar, input$zone, input$comp)
})

output$graf <- renderPlot ({

        if ((input$yvar == "BMI") & (input$zone == "Front Row") & (input$comp == "None")){  
        plots[[1]]
    } else if ((input$yvar == "BMI") & (input$zone == "Front Row") & (input$comp == "Front Row")){  
        plots[[1]]
    } else if ((input$yvar == "BMI") & (input$zone == "Front Row") & (input$comp == "Second Row")) {
        plots[[28]]
    } else if ((input$yvar == "BMI") & (input$zone == "Front Row") & (input$comp == "Back Row")) {
        plots[[29]]
```

... there are 111 of these statements.

I am losing steam with this app, because I want to add more to it, and I know there is an easier way to use this with the `switch` function or something else, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Maybe making a function to dynamically create those plots instead of pre-making them would do it.

Comment: @cory Thank you for the response. I am struggling with this immensely. Could you perhaps guide me in the best way of doing this?

Comment: Following a general programming rule: if you copy things more than twice: generalize. My experience is that things are then getting easier.

Comment: Thank you for the input, @tpetzoldt , appreciated. Could you show me how to implement that rule in this context?

Comment: Generalization and use of functions is a general programming technique, independent of context. It is best learnt by small examples.

Comment: It would look something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345782/shiny-passing-inputvar-to-aes-in-ggplot2

Comment: Cheers, @cory, thank you for taking the time.