# R Shiny how to refer to inputs that are part of dynamic number of inputs

Tags: r, shiny

So, I need to make a shiny app that takes a dynamic number of inputs to eventually do dimension reduction, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to refer to what's in my inputs when I have a dynamic number of them. I'm using the iris dataset and the inputs are the variables. Part of what I need to do is plot 2 of them with a k means, but I'm just trying to 1st make a basic plot.  What I have so far is

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(2,
           textInput(inputId = "number", label = "number of selectInput",value = 2)
    ),
    column(8,
           plotOutput("distPlot")),
    column(2,
           uiOutput(outputId = "putselect"))
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  output$putselect = renderUI(
    if(input$number != 0 ){
      lapply(1:(input$number), function(i){
        selectInput(inputId = paste0("var",i), label = paste0("input ",i), choices   = names(iris))
      })
    }
  )
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes(x = input$var1, y = input$var2, color = Species)) +
      geom_point()
    
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In my output$distplot what goes in the ggplot x and y? The way I have it now it shows up and the labels on the graph change, but there are no points on the graph. I'm new to using Shiny so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shiny: passing input$var to aes() in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345782/shiny-passing-inputvar-to-aes-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

instead of `aes` use `aes_string` like:

```
ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$var1,
                        y = input$var2,
                        color = "Species"
                        )
       )
```

note to **quote** the variables supplied as a string (*Species* in this case)

see: [Shiny: passing input$var to aes() in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345782/shiny-passing-inputvar-to-aes-in-ggplot2)

Comment: That works. Thank you. Additionally, when I reduce dimensions I'll want to refer to all the inputs there. How will I do that?

Comment: Not sure if I understood: you can treat `input` like other lists, e.g. `names(input)` will give you the names of all input elements which you could then filter for all inputs labelled "var..." and pick the corresponding variables for dimensionality reduction. Is that what you intend to do, or some UI manipulation like bulk showing/hiding UI elements?

Comment: I think that will work. Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions.

Comment: The question was certainly OK, I just wasn't sure whether it was a server-side (handling input flow) or UI-side (arranging input elements) issue.